# How to replace .Except with .RemoveRange?

Tags: c#

I am trying to update an existing list by removing certain items based on some condition. My current approach uses 2-step process where 1st) I use `.Except` and create a new list and 2nd). I assign this newly created list to the existing one.

My goal is to achieve this by either using `.RemoveAll` or `.RemoveRange` without loop or creating new list.

How to do that?

Code:

```
public async Task<MyObject> MyFunction(MyObject existingEntity, MyObject incomingEntity)
{
    var commonItems = existingEntity.items.Join(incomingEntity.items,
        itemToRemove => new { itemToRemove.id },
        existingItem => new { existingItem.id },
        (itemToRemove, existingItem) => new
        {
            itemToRemove,
            existingItem
        }).ToList();

    // Thinking of following lines to replace with .RemoveRange
    var updatedItems = existingEntity.items
        .Except(commonItems.Select(x => x.itemToRemove)).ToList();

    existingEntity.items = updatedLineItems;

    return existingEntity;
}
```

When I try [.Remove](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.remove?view=net-7.0) then it is working as expected but I have to use loop,

```
var itemsToRemove = commonItems.Select(x => x.itemToRemove);
foreach (var item in itemsToRemove)
{
    existingEntity.items.Remove(item);
}
```

But when I try with [.RemoveAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeall?view=net-7.0), it is not working (I may not be using it correctly):

```
 existingEntity.items.RemoveAll(x =>
                x.id.Equals(itemsToRemove.Select(y => y.id)));
```

Comment: What do you mean by "better"? Also, is this EF Core or not? You added that tag but haven't mentioned it in the question. That might change things dramatically.

Comment: @DavidG Thanks for pointing that out. I have rephrased my question for better clarity.

Comment: You don't need to create any of the intermediate lists.

Comment: @AluanHaddad could you please provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

```
  public async Task<MyObject> MyFunction(MyObject existingEntity, MyObject incomingEntity)
        {
            var commonItems = existingEntity.items.Join(incomingEntity.items,
          itemToRemove => itemToRemove.id,
          existingItem => existingItem.id,
          (itemToRemove, existingItem) => itemToRemove).ToList();

            existingEntity.items.RemoveAll(commonItems.Contains);

            return existingEntity;
        }
```

Comment: This is still creating a list which I want to eliminate. I am looking for the approach where I can use `.RemoveRange` on `existingEntity.items` using `commonItems.Select(x => x.itemToRemove)`

Comment: I just made a correction to my answer.

Comment: you are now updating`commonItems` logic which I don't want to. Plus how does `commonItems.Contains` would even work here?

Comment: @GThree If you don't want to change `commonItems`, you can keep it as it is and create `var itemsToRemove = commonItems.Select(x => x.itemToRemove);` as you did originally; then, `existingEntity.items.RemoveAll(itemsToRemove.Contains);` should do the trick. You may want to explore the concept of _method group_ :) Example fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/NNFuzD

Answer (score 0):

I was able to acheive this by following:

```
existingEntity.items.RemoveAll(r => 
        commonItems.Select(x => x.itemToRemove).Any(a => a.id == r.id));
```

Full Code:

```
public async Task<MyObject> MyFunction(MyObject existingEntity, MyObject incomingEntity)
{
    var commonItems = existingEntity.items.Join(incomingEntity.items,
        itemToRemove => new { itemToRemove.id },
        existingItem => new { existingItem.id },
        (itemToRemove, existingItem) => new
        {
            itemToRemove,
            existingItem
        }).ToList();

   existingEntity.items.RemoveAll(r => 
        commonItems.Select(x => x.itemToRemove).Any(a => a.id == r.id));

    return existingEntity;
}
```